# setinterval lose focus on input field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

As I try to use setInterval function input fields in bootstrap modal get focus out

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("hi");
}, 5000);
```

input focus automatically out while try to write in an input field.

[ISSUE](https://streamable.com/r5jwx)

Comment: What does the `runFunction()` do? It might help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate.

Comment: @showdev nothing i just edited that..

Comment: I've actually seen that happening before, in Chrome. Try not to have that interval or timeout while there is any focus :) The fix depends on the rest of the situation.

Comment: Whilst the video demonstrates your problem, you need to provide more code. ..

Comment: while setinterval is running and i open bootstrap modal and in bootstrap modal there are input fields so while i try to type than lose focuses just like the video

Comment: @René than i should stop setInterval while focus on any field?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/w9q2dLaz/) based on the code provided.

Comment: @showdev it will not happens in desktop, it will be arise in mobile in chrome browser, not in all mobiles too

Comment: @NiravJoshi well pausing it will probably prevent the issue in your case. My case was not exactly the same but it acts like the same (possibly?) bug. So if the interval is not strictly necessary it saves you a lot of headaches to just fix it the easiest way possible instead of figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might not be what you're looking for, and I'm not sure a real answer can be given but putting code in comments is ugly.
Read comments for info about the question itself.

- Happens in Google Chrome Android(unsure if version or phone or keyboard matters)
- Happens with delayed functions like timeout and setinterval
- I guessed it had to do with a repaint, but if a console.log triggers it as well... I have no idea

Below the code that resembles my production case and with the "fix" (for my case) in it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Any var declarations don't seem to matter
    var foo = null;

    // Easy way out ... if needed you can delay to do stuff onBlur
    // Find current focused element and escape if its an input
    if (document.activeElement.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        return;
    }   

    // Here some random style change that triggered the bug
    randomFunc();
}, 210);
```

Comment: Problem solved with this, and yes it is happening due to calling infinite function and it is causing sometimes in chrome mobile browser. thank you so much :)